# Выделяются ли запятыми вставные конструкции в скобках. (И остальное, заодно, проверьте: вдруг ошибка вкралась.)

Tags: пунктуация

1)Полуостров Коулун, станция метро «Джордан». Оказалось, мое
чердачное жилище, (которое я все же разыскал по записанному вблокноте адресу), находится в двух шагах от вышеописанного места.
2)Возвращаясь из привокзальных переулков, обратил внимание накомпанию бомжей. Эти не были похожи на транзитных пассажиров, (которые, скоротав ночь на улице, ехали дальше): профессионалы!
3) «Не в том дело, – продолжал инструктор, – нищий
мальчуган-бродяжка, (их здесь много), может подойти и попроситьденег, а если не дашь, – схватит ботинки и убежит».

Comment: Обратите внимание на опечатку. На компанию - раздельно.

Comment: Спасибо, этого в моем тексте нет, когда копировал, вышла опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, зачем придаточные предложения оформляются как вставные. Их вполне можно было выделить запятыми. Если же оставить скобки:

1). Полуостров Коулун, станция метро «Джордан». Оказалось, мое чердачное жилище (которое я все же разыскал по записанному вблокноте адресу) находится в двух шагах от вышеописанного места. - ***Вставное предложение уже выделено скобками. Другой знак не требуется.***

2). Возвращаясь из привокзальных переулков, обратил внимание на компанию бомжей. Эти не были похожи на транзитных пассажиров (которые, скоротав ночь на улице, ехали дальше) - профессионалы! - ***Придаточное выделено скобками вместо запятых. Тире ставим, так как вторая часть сложного предложения практически противопоставлена первой.***

3) «Не в том дело, – продолжал инструктор, – нищий мальчуган-бродяжка (их здесь много) может подойти и попросить денег, а если не дашь, - схватит ботинки и убежит». - ***Скобки не дублируем запятыми, обычный вариант оформления вводного предложения.***

Comment: Спасибо. И в этих предложениях запятые вокруг скобок тоже не нужны?  1)Помолившись местным божествам в монастыре По Линь, (название которого переводится как «Драгоценный лотос»), «одолжил» у них два яблока и продолжил путь.  2)Как я уже писал выше, в этой стране, (в отличие, к примеру, от соседней Монголии), все города по ночам переливаются огнями.

Comment: 1)Помолившись местным божествам в монастыре По Линь (название которого переводится как «Драгоценный лотос»), «одолжил» у них два яблока и продолжил путь. 2)Как я уже писал выше, в этой стране (в отличие, к примеру, от соседней Монголии), все города по ночам переливаются огнями. В этих примерах остаётся запятая за скобкой.

Answer (score 0):

В первом и в третьем предложении запятая должна стоят после скобок. Знаки середины предложения (запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, тире), оказавшиеся перед открывающей вставку скобкой, переносятся за закрывающую вставку скобку,  перед открывающей вставку скобкой может стоять только многоточие.

Что касается вашего второго предложения, то оно не совсем понятное: после двоеточия должно следовать пояснение, разъяснение. Слово "профессионалы" не является разъяснением к "дальше", а двоеточие относится именно к этому слову.

Если все же исходить из формального подхода, то двоеточие **(в этом примере)** должно стоять внутри скобок, а после скобок по основному правилу должна стоять запятая.

[См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://%D0%A1%D0%BC.:%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) ( § 158, п. 1).

Comment: "Профессионалы" вообще не относятся ко вставке, то есть я хотел написать так, чтобы фразу в скобках можно было опустить.   Эти не были похожи на транзитных пассажиров, – которые, скоротав ночь на улице, ехали дальше,– профессионалы! Или так...   Эти не были похожи на транзитных пассажиров,– профессионалы! (но здесь без вставки, а она нужна)

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что профессионалы - это транзитные пассажиры, тогда поставьте точку после скобок. И профессионалы - с прописной.

Comment: Возвращаясь из привокзальных переулков, обратил внимание на компанию бомжей. Эти, - истинные профессионалы, - в корне отличались от транзитных пассажиров, которые скоротав одну ночь на улице, ехали дальше. Теперь нормально?

Comment: Такое обособление возможно. Только надо оставить или запятые или тире.

Comment: А мне кажется, что и то, и другое.

Comment: При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания: Вы садитесь в коляску, — это так приятно после вагона, — и катите по степной дороге (Ч.). ***Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно***.

Comment: Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, необходимого по условиям контекста: Жизненный материал — все то, что Достоевский называл «подробностями текущей жизни», — не изучают. Просто писатели живут <... > внутри этого материала (Пауст.);